Flutter keyboard issue, while converting a text into fullwidth with romaji keyboard
In the textfield I am having a condition to convert entering character into fullwidth(in onChanged). Using normal English keyboard the char is entering as full width while typing,
But while using Romaji keyboard in iPhone, the 1st char is replaced by 2nd input character, I couldn't make a full sentyour textence using romaji keyboard.
Any solution for this?
I couldn't type full sentence using romaji japanese keyboard
